# Jquery Ajax working on localhost (xammp) but not working on Server (cpanel)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Jquery Ajax working fine on localhost (xammp) but not working on Server (cpanel) !
also ajax with Javascript working fine , but throught JQuery it has problem ! (on server)
i changed send method to POST but problem same.

this is my website :
concert20.ir

an this is js code:

```
var arr=[];
function func1(id,status){
        var str;
        var a=id.split('-');
        // a[0] = chair number
        // a[1] = singer id
        // a[2] = place
        length=arr.length;
        if(status=='رزور شده')
        {
            // check that who resereved it?
            var index=jQuery.inArray(parseInt(a[0]), arr);
            if(index>=0)
            {
                // unreserved ...
                //arr[index]=-1;
                arr.splice(index, 1);
                length=arr.length;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({reservefunc:0,chairnum:a[0],singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#drawtable").html(result);
                    }
                });

                if(length==0)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({showdetails:0,chairnum:arr,singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#card").html(result);
                    }
                });
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({showdetails:1,chairnum:arr,singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#card").html(result);
                    }
                });
                }
            }
        }
        else if(status=='قابل خرید')
        {

            // reserve ...
            arr.push(parseInt(a[0]));

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                type: "GET",
                data: ({reservefunc:1,chairnum:a[0],singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                success: function(result){
                    $("#drawtable").html(result);
                }
            });  


            sts=$("input#checksts").val();
            if(sts==-1)
            {
                var index=jQuery.inArray(parseInt(a[0]), arr);
                arr.splice(index, 1);
                alert('این صندلی قبلا خریداری شده است');
            }
            length=arr.length;
            if(length==0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({showdetails:0,chairnum:arr,singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#card").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ServerReply.php', 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: ({showdetails:1,chairnum:arr,singerid:a[1],place:a[2]}),
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#card").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }   
}
```

**UPDATE**
i found the problem!
the server was context-sensitive and i did not observe it
i changed **S**erverReply.php to **s**erverReply.php and it worked fine ...

Answer (score 0):

try to write absolute url save to versions of ulr in var and comment , un comment respectively

```
var mainurl = "http://localhost/project/serverReply.php"

var mainurl = "http://xeample.com/project/serverReply.php"
```

try if it can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "ServerReply.php",
        cache : false,
        async : true,
        global : false,
        data : {
                 "showdetails":0,
                 "chairnum":arr
            }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        //Do something
    });
```

Comment: i checked it into chrome web developer tools! and it said 404 error! but my code working fine on localhost ...

destination page is : **s**erverReply.php but "inspect element" on google chrome said: 404 **S**erverReply